# Can you subclass a DependencyObject, changing a currently-read/write property into a read-only property in the subclass?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, dependencyobject

Title says it all.  Not thinking this is possible due to the way DependencyProperties work, but figured I'd ask.  Can you change a read-write property to a read-only property in a subclass?

Comment: Couldn't you use inheritance `public class MyDependencyObject : DependencyObject{}` and then just override the field you want with a read-only version? `public override readonly string MyString` can't get to an IDE atm so not sure if this is super helpful

Comment: Yes, but how do you override a dependency property? Remember the CLR accessors for a DP are exactly just that... accessors.  They don't stop you from setting the values in other ways (e.g. SetValue, etc.)

Comment: @MarquelV damn you're right. Could you do something like this? `public string MyString => base.MyString`?

Comment: Again, that's just POCO properties, not DP properties.  You register a DP property specifically as normal or as read-only.  That's why I don't think you can change it.

Comment: From what I've been reading I think you're right... apologies for not being useful

Comment: No worries.  They say if you have to try really hard to get something to work, chances are there's an easier way you're not considering.

Comment: I don't think there is a 'common' way to do that. Accessibility is a feature of a dependency property, and is not belong to property metadata that can be override. But dependency property handle accessibility in a very simple way, if you only use subclass, you can still change is by reflecting through some pravite members.